# Phpunit, expects a method run two times, but what if it didnt run at all?

Tags: php

Well thats interesting. Lets mock:

```
$stub = $this->getMock ('Testclass');
$stub->expects($this->exactly(2))->method('runthistwice');
```

so, this fails:

```
$stub->runthistwice();
```

this also fails:

```
$stub->runthistwice();
$stub->runthistwice();
$stub->runthistwice();
```

and this passes:

```
$stub->runthistwice();
$stub->runthistwice();
```

So far so good. But if I dont invoke `$stub->runthistwice();` at all, the test still passes! Its not logical! What Im doing wrong?

Comment: `Expectation failed for method name is equal to <string:runthistwice> when invoked 2 time(s).
Method was expected to be called 2 times, actually called 0 times.` --- `PHPUnit 4.3.3`

Comment: hmmm, Im using 4.2.2, I do this updating then, a sec....

Comment: no effect, test is still passes

Comment: provide the complete reproducible piece of code that we could take and run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code posted is valid and correct. If `$stub->runthistwice();` is not called *at all* then PHPUnit **will** mark the test as failed (as stated in the comments by [zerkms](https://stackoverflow.com/users/251311/zerkms)).

Logic dictates the defect is elsewhere in the code.

If you attempt to create a [Short, Self Contained, Correct, Example](http://sscce.org/) with the *exact* code that is run, the odds are you will find this defect all by yourself.

If you do, it is perfectly acceptable to post your findings as an answer to your own question.